# How to wait for an HTML Object element to be fully loaded

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

In my application built with HTML and jQuery, I am using an Object element to embed a page that is also from my application within another page. For ease of explanation, let's say that I am using an Object element to embed page A into page B.

Here is the situation: When a user clicks a button, the onClick method loads page A into an object element on page B. Then, I remove the header and footer of page A within the Object element (doing this in the onClick method as well). The header and footer are being removed to avoid redundancy, as page B is a part of the same application and thus has the same header and footer.

My issue is that the part of the function that removes the header and footer is not waiting for the object element to fully load page A. Thus, when it tries to remove the elements from the DOM, it cannot find them because they are not fully loaded.

For testing purposes, I have just been setting a timeout to force the second part of the function to wait. But I would like to have it run immediately after the object element is loaded so it appears more seamless. My onClick function looks something like below:

```
function onClick() {
jQuery('#page_a_object_container').show();
jQuery('#page_a_object').attr('data', '/link/to/page/a');

// I would like the code below to wait to be ran until the object element is fully loaded
let headerAndFooterParent = document.querySelector('#page_a_object').contentDocument.children[0];
headerAndFooterParent.removeChild(headerAndFooterParent.children[1]);
headerAndFooterParent.removeChild(headerAndFooterParent.children[0]);
}
```

Anyone know of a good approach to take here?

Comment: You could operate on window on load; that should await all elements to load.

Comment: Are you using JQUERY's .load() to load the embedded page?

Comment: @Mifo no, I am setting the 'data' property on the object element to be the link to the page that I wish to embed and then using jQuery to show the container of the object element

Comment: So how does that object work? I am assuming there is a listener of some sort on the data attribute that triggers the load? If so, that code that is doing the load should have a callback where the other code should get executed.

Comment: @Mifo while I am a bit new to jQuery, I don't believe there is any listener. The container div of the object has its display set to 'none', and the object just sits in the div with no defined 'data' property. When the button is clicked, the display of the container div is set to show, and the object element gets passed the link to its data property

Comment: So at some point something is going out to your server and loading '/link/to/page/a' into something is that correct? Is it possible to show a little more detail as to what '#page_a_object' actually is? You are dealing with an asynchronous operation that is still doing its thing (i.e., loading from '/link/to/page/a') and subsequent code executing before that is done. The actual code that is loading '/link/to/page/a' is the area where there will be a callback function in which you need to place your code to remove the header and footer.